# Why does framebuffer freeze in Derelict3?

Tags: opengl, d, fbo

I am using Derelict3 which uses the specific openGL3 standard and I am having an issue with the screen freezing (not updating) if glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) is called, and the depth buffers not working if it is not. I have noticed that calls to set the clear color and enable depth testing are ignored if they are made prior to setting up the SDL_GL context and reloading Derelict3. I had to make them in the following order:

```
win=SDL_CreateWindow("3Doodle", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, w, h,     flags); 
if(!win){ 
       writefln("Error creating SDL window"); 
      SDL_Quit(); 
} 

context=SDL_GL_CreateContext(win); 
SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1); 

glVersion=DerelictGL3.reload(); 

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); 

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
glClearDepth(1.0); 

glCullFace(GL_BACK); 
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
```

While this sorted out depth culling while writing to the standard double buffer, when I implement a framebuffer object with a renderBuffer as the new depth buffer I get a freeze... the program compiles and runs without warnings, but the rendered image to the screen aligned quad remains fixed. If I comment out glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); the camera moves freely but the the rendered image pays no mind to depth testing and simply draws objects in order.

The framebuffer initialization code is:

```
//fbo 
glEnable (GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB); 
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo); 
assert(fbo > 0); 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo); 

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo); 
assert(rbo > 0); 
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo); 
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, projMat.w, projMat.h); 
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo); 
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0); 

glGenTextures(1, &fbon); 
assert(fbon > 0); 
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbon); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, projMat.w, projMat.h, 0, GL_RGBA,     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);    
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbon, 0); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); 

 glGenTextures(1, &fboc); 
assert(fboc > 0); 
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboc); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, projMat.w, projMat.h, 0, GL_RGBA,     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);    
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboc, 0); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); 

glGenTextures(1, &fbop); 
assert(fbop > 0); 
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbop); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, projMat.w, projMat.h, 0, GL_RGBA,     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);    
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbop, 0); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); 

int status=glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER); 
assert(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE); 

buffs=[GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2]; 
glDrawBuffers(3, buffs.ptr); 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

The code calling the fbo in draw() is:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo); 
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

glUseProgram(shad); 
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_TRUE, player.mat.ptr); 

current.draw(); 

glUseProgram(0); 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); 

rend.draw();
```

I am at a loss as the same codes is working in c# as it ought.

Comment: Have you tried calling `glGetError()` to see if anything has gone wrong on the OpenGL side of things?

Answer (score 2):

My stupidity. Forgot to specify glDepthFunc